# Create serverfolder if filepath does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I have a controller method that handles file uploads from a jquery script. I specify the filepath with the following code `Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles/"), qqfile);` I would like to add a parameter that specifies a subfolder for the file, but i can only specify existing folders.

Is there any easy fix to create the subfolder on the server if it doesn't exist?

This is my controller method:

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(string qqfile)
{
    var file = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        var stream = Request.InputStream;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["qqfile"]))
        {
            // IE
            HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files[0];
            stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            file = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles/"), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[0].FileName));
        }
        else
        {
            //Webkit, Mozilla
            file = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles/"), qqfile);
        }

        var buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(file, buffer);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message }, "application/json");
    }

    return Json(new { success = true }, "text/html");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
        string path = "~/UserFiles/subfolder/";
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        //todo
```

Or this should work

```
string folder= "subfolder";
var path= Server.MapPath("~/UserFiles/" + folder);
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(path);
if (directory.Exists == false)
{
    directory.Create();
}
//todo
```

Comment: Yes, however CreateDirectory won't create a folder for me.

Comment: @Tobias: why? Do you have an exception message? I suppose folder rights for the app pool identity is your problem. Please also check the edited code for the right folder syntax!